# Failed to load PDF document using aws-sdk in SuiteScript

Tags: amazon-s3, netsuite, suitescript

I have a problem when uploading pdf files to S3.
the upload process is successful and I can see my files in the bucket.
but whenever I try to download or view my files in the bucket I receive this error  "Error
Failed to load PDF document." Tried to open the file from different browser but through same error. here is my code to handle this
the library using from "https://gist.github.com/binhp/52e2254420a638d9da5c4cf33dde3c46"

/**

- @NApiVersion 2.x
- @NScriptType Suitelet
  */
  define(["N/https", "N/file", "N/log", "/SuiteScripts/ns-aws-s3" , "N/encode"], function (https, nfile, nLog, AWS, nEncode) {

function onRequest(scriptContext) {

```
var awsAccessKey = "";
var awsSecretKey = "";
var awsBucketName = "";
var awsContentEncoding = "UTF-8";

var selectedFile = nfile.load({ id: 11987    });
var fileNameSplit = selectedFile.name.split(".");
var fileExtension = fileNameSplit.pop();
var fileName = fileNameSplit.shift();

var selectedFileContent = selectedFile.getContents();


var keyFileName = fileName + "-" + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;

var option = { 
  region: "ap-southeast-1",
  accessKeyId: awsAccessKey,
  secretAccessKey: awsSecretKey,
};
var s3Obj = new AWS.S3(option);

const params ={
  
    Bucket: awsBucketName,
    Key: keyFileName,
    Body: selectedFileContent,
    // ContentEncoding: awsContentEncoding,
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256', // Optional
    ACL:   "public-read-write" ,
    ContentType: getContentTypeByFileExtension(fileExtension),
  };

  s3Obj.putObject( params , function (err,data) {
  
    if (err) {
      nLog.error("s3Error", JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
      nLog.debug("S3putObject", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }
  );

var preSignedUrlParams = {
  Bucket: awsBucketName,
  Key: keyFileName,
};

var preSignedUrl = s3Obj.getSignedUrl("getObject", preSignedUrlParams);

nLog.debug("Pre-signed URL:", preSignedUrl);

// Retrieve file content from the pre-signed URL
var response = https.get({ url: preSignedUrl });

if (response.code === 200) {
  var fileContent = response.body;
  // Process the file content here
} else {
  nLog.debug("Error retrieving file content. HTTP response code:", response.code);
}


var file = nfile.create({
  name: "file_name.pdf",
  fileType: nfile.Type.PDF,
  contents: fileContent,
  folder: -20, // Replace with the appropriate folder ID
});
var fileId = file.save();
nLog.debug("file save with id" + fileId)
```

}

function getContentTypeByFileExtension(fileExtension) {
var contentType;

```
switch (fileExtension.toLowerCase()) {
  case "pdf":
    contentType = "application/pdf";
    break;
  case "png":
    contentType = "image/png";
    break;
  case "jpg":
  case "jpeg":
    contentType = "image/jpeg";
    break;
  case "txt":
    contentType = "text/plain";
    break;
  // Add more cases for other file extensions as needed
  default:
    contentType = "application/octet-stream"; // Fallback content type
    break;
}

return contentType;
```

}

return {
onRequest: onRequest,
};
});

However When i try to get the uploaded file from s3 bucket it retrieve the content correctly.

I tried to use Upload() function rather than putObject() but always recive this error "Error: code 400: " no message body

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'render' module to read the file contents and try to upload those file contents it should work.

```
let renderer = render.create();
renderer.addCustomDataSource({
          format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
          alias: "pdf data",
          data: pdfData,
        });
 var newfile = renderer.renderAsPdf();
let fileContents = newfile.getContents();
```

and upload the file contents.